# Prototype Ajax request adds long string of functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, prototype, prototypejs

I get a long list of functions (from prototype) added to my Ajax.Request parameters when working with JSONs!
It seems like it has something to do with my for loop her it is:

```
for (x in Elements) {    
            if (typeof Elements[x] !== "function") {

                var Element = {
                    'ElementID': Elements[x].options['ElementID'],
                    'ElementValue': Elements[x].Value
                };

                Params.push(Object.toJSON(Element, true));
            }
        }
```

My Data is like this:

```
"{"ElementID":"MainPage_1"}", "{"ElementID":"Sub_1_1"}", "{"ElementID":"Sub_1_2"}", "{"ElementID":"MainPage_2"}"
```

i used Object.toJSON to get a JSON

My Ajax.Request:

```
new Ajax.Request('AjaxClass.php', {
     method: 'post',
     parameters: Params
});
```

I get my Request like this:

```
new AjaxClass($_REQUEST);

class AjaxClass{
  function __construct(Array $request){
     var_dump($request);
  }
}
```

Everything gets send normally but my $Request array has a long list functions at the end it seems like a prototype.js class or something like that here a small snippet:

```
function each
(iterator,context){var index=0;try{this._each(function(value){iterator.call(context,value,index++);}
);}catch(e){if(e!=$break)throw e;}
        return this;
```

Do you know where it comes from?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Use hasOwnProperty as well as checking if Elements[x] is not a function. For object instances you should not have them start with a capital as that would indicate a constructor function

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit! To get rid of the prototype functions give the Ajax.Request a key value pair as parameter like this:

```
new Ajax.Request('AjaxClass.php', {
     method: 'post',
     parameters: {
         JSON: Params
     }
});
```

And to get the request simply add the JSON key to $_REQUEST like this:

```
$_REQUEST["JSON"]
```